# How do I migrate default home flexi page assignment from one organization to another using ANT Migration Tool?

Tags: deployment, ant, change-set, migration-tool, migration

I have FlexiPage Home_Page_Default.flexipage assigned as Default Home Lightning Page for all profiles in one sandbox. I need to migrate it to another sandbox and assign as Default Home Lightning Page for all profiles in the destination sandbox.

I am able to retrieve and deploy that flexipage but looks like I am not able to assign it automatically as Default Home Lightning Page for all profiles in the destination sandbox using Force.com ANT Migration Tool or changeset.

Is that possible to migrate default home flexi page assignment from one organization to another using ANT Migration Tool or changeset?

If this is possible then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was informed by my colleague that to deploy default home flexi page assignment we need to retrieve and deploy custom tab component with name `standard-home`